# Lista de arquivos dá erros ao passar por .decode()

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

No seguinte código para transferência de arquivos utilizando sockets em Python:

Cliente:

```
lista_arquivos = ['C:\Users\fulano\Imagens\passaro.jpg', 'C:\Users\fulano\Imagens\cachorro.jpg', 'C:\Users\fulano\Imagens\gato.jpg']

    def transferir_arquivos(self):

        for arquivo in self.lista_arquivos:
            print(arquivo)
            host = socket.gethostname()
            port = 9000
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((host, port))
            # enviado o nome do arquivo
            nome_arquivo = os.path.basename(arquivo)
            s.send(nome_arquivo.encode('utf-8'))
            # próprio arquivo enviado
            with open(f'{arquivo}', 'rb') as arq:
                print(f"Transferindo {arquivo}")
                s.send(arq.read())
                print("Arquivo enviado")
                s.close()
                arq.close()
        self.excluir_lista()
```

Servidor:

```
serversock = socket.socket() host = socket.gethostname() port = 9000 serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) serversock.bind((host, port)) serversock.listen(5)


while True:
    clientsocket, address = serversock.accept()
    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(address))
    dados = clientsocket.recv(32)
    print(dados) # mostra o conteudo de dados
    nome = dados.decode()
    print(f"Nome: {nome}")
    with open(nome, 'wb') as f:
        print('arquivo aberto')
        print('Recebendo dados...')
        data = clientsocket.recv(301149653)
        f.write(data)
        print("Enviando")
        f.close()
        print('Transferencia Completa!!!') clientsocket.close() print('conexão encerrada')
```

É retornado o seguinte quando chega no segundo item da lista:

```
Got a connection from ('meu_ip', 55159)
b'passaro.jpg'
Nome: passaro.jpg
arquivo aberto
Recebendo dados...
Enviando
Transferencia Completa!!!
Got a connection from ('meu_ip', 55160)
b'cachorro.jpg\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\server_side.py", line 17, in <module>
    nome = dados.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Geralmente não especifico a encodificação, mas se serve de ajuda, github.com/Diolante/Servidor-Web-Simples-em-Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é que você está presumindo que o recv() só vai receber os bytes enviados por um comando send(). Mas o TCP não enquadra as mensagens, é tudo uma tripa de bytes, então seu recv() está recebendo o nome do arquivo (do primeiro send) e também um pedaço do conteúdo do arquivo (segundo send).

Para fazer funcionar com o menor número possível de alterações, sugiro que você transforme o nome do arquivo numa string de 32 bytes fixos:

```
   d = arquivo.encode('utf8')
   d = d + (b" " * (32 - len(d)))
   s.send(d)
```

No outro lado, você continua fazendo recv(32), que vai receber os 32 bytes esperados, e remove os espaços fazendo

```
nome = dados.decode().strip()
```

Mas tendo em mente que é uma solução porca, que vai quebrar se o nome do arquivo tiver mais que 32 caracteres de tamanho. É só pra fazer funcionar e você ter algo funcionando para então aprimorar. O correto é inserir alguma codificação na tripa de bytes para você saber onde termina o nome e começa o conteúdo.